# How to install/use cardano-serialization-lib

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, emurgo

I follow [this guide](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/overview) to get start with cardano-serialization-lib.
Install nodejs package with:

```
npm i @emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs
```

Still can't get it running. The module 'rust-lib' can't be found. And of course when try to `import 'rust-lib'` there is an error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rust-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

So how do I get the module visible?

Step-by-step guide would be really appreciated. I don't have very deep knowledge about how nodejs or rust works.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I have to `import 'rust-lib'` but instead I have to

```
import CardanoWasm = require('@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs')
```

Get the idea from [this answer](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-get-publickey-from-privatekey).